# Bounty rules clarification

Tags: discussion, bounties

According to bounty **rules**:

> Bounties expire after seven days. After a bounty expires, there is an
>   additional 24 hour window for the bounty to be awarded so that late
>   answers may be considered. If it remains unawarded and one or more
>   answers posted during the bounty period have a score of 2 or more,
>   half the bounty will be automatically awarded to the one with the
>   highest score.

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361874/how-can-i-trigger-an-event-when-the-devices-profile-is-changed/17471545#17471545) offered a +100 bounty which had ended yesterday and the **grace period** also ended. 3 answers given during bounty period. **2** of them got **1 upvote** (so equal score).

Still it remains **unawarded**. None of 2 upvoted answers got 2 score. So what will be this post's **bounty distribution**?

Comment: Nobody gets the bounty. (If it were going to be automatically given, it would have been assigned at the end of the grace period).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of the answers meet the requirement to receive the bounty, so it is forfeit and goes to no one.

If any of the posts had received 2 upvotes, and were not manually awarded the bounty by the Bounty Giver, then the post with the highest upvotes would receive half the bounty (50).

However, since none of the answers meet the criteria, the entire bounty is forfeit and goes to no one.

Comment: if later one of these answer got remaining 1 upvote,does the half bounty awarded then?

Comment: @ridoy if the bounty has expired and so has the grace period, NO. Did you [read the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work?rq=1)?

Comment: Ok,clear now..@AaronBertrand

Answer (score 6):

The bounty will **not** be automatically awarded to any post, and unless the OP assigns it manually it'll dissipate.

Remember that the bounty is an *advertiment* cost and is not guaranteed to be awarded, and is never refunded.

Comment: RaghavSood clears it well.